# Ember 1.13 - DS.attr deprecation

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, deprecation-warning

I've upgraded to Ember v1.13.0, and now I have a couple of deprecation warnings (as expected) but I can't find any clue as to how to get rid of them. Ember has provided some [links](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_deprecate-using-the-same-function-as-getter-and-setter-in-computed-properties) to the guides but they are useless and disappointing.

The most common deprecation I have is for the `DS.attr('type')` method on `Ember.Model`.

Here is the console trace:

[image: console trace]

How does the new syntax work? Please provide an example by converting this model into the new format

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Order = DS.Model.extend({
  price: DS.attr('number'),
  date: DS.attr('string'),
  shopName: DS.attr('string'),
  shippingStatus: DS.attr('string'),
  destination: DS.attr('string'),
  dueFor: DS.attr('string')
});

export default Order;
```

Comment: Mind adding the deprecation warning and it's message?

Comment: I've included it in my edit @Kitler

Comment: The error message you have linked is not related to `DS.attr`, afaik there is no new syntax for models, the error message is related to computed properties.

Comment: What version of ember data are you on?

Comment: Version `1.0.0-beta.16.1`

Comment: Update to `1.0.0-beta.17` to fix it, close voting as a dupe to the question @AlanTam linked.